# What are some good platforms & resources to start investing?

Tags: investing, stock-markets, starting-out-investing, shares

I've been interested in buying and selling stocks/shares for a while, but I don't know which platform to use. There seem to be various options, but it's hard to see which are run by legitimate companies. Are there any resources to help a beginner who only wants to invest a small amount?

To be clear, I mainly intend to use their simulation options and don't want to risk more than the amount I put in. I have a total budget of £100, real money. When it's gone, it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

### Platforms

I personally recommend [Interactive Brokers](https://interactivebrokers.co.uk). They have low fees and a wide array of products, you can trade anything from stocks to options and futures. You can also open a "paper money" account, that is, a demo account. Yet, to find the broker that suits best your style and is available in your geography, check out this [hall of fame](https://www.investopedia.com/best-online-brokers-4587872).

### Educational Resources

The crème de la crème:

- [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/)
- [The Motley Fool](https://fool.com)
- [SeekingAlpha](https://seekingalpha.com)

Plus Wikipedia! Sometimes it's worth it to spend time there to get a very deep understanding of the financial product or asset you want to get hold of.

Comment: I think that with only  £100 designated for opening an account,  minimum account size at Interactive Brokers may be an issue.  And while I trade there and wouldn't leave, it's not the easiest platform to learn to use. To their credit, stable platform,  instant execution with instant  trade reporting and account updating, they pass through ECN rebates, low margin rates, and they make an effort to locate hard to borrow stocks.  Seeking Alpha is a good source of info but beware of their $ubscription agenda.

Comment: They recently cut off their minimum account size. You can deposit as little as $1 now. Moreover, if you're on [IBKR Lite](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=45500), there are no maintenance fees and US stock trading is free of charge.

Comment: What was the final outcome on payment for order flow for  IBKR Lite?   Did they follow through with that order did they scrap that idea?

Comment: No idea. I'm on Pro.